# My friend deleted something I owned in Mnecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I wanted to show my friend the book I was writing in Minecraft Nintendo Switch version. They were clearing out their inventory as I gave it to them, and it appears they accidentally cleared it out with the rest of their items.

Is there a way I can get it back?

Comment: Not really unless you were playing in a online server which might have had a mod which acted like a "recycling bin"

Comment: Big oof..well thanks for using your time to help me! :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get it back unless you have some sort of backup file of this world.  if it is an online server they may have a mod with an "undo" or "recycle bin" feature that will allow you to access those lost items.  Being that you are playing on the Switch it is most likely that your only chance would be if you had a backup file from manual or auto save.  If not then the items would be gone.

Comment: Yea your right...well thanks you for using time out of your day to help me :)